# Firebase - Will firebase-messaging work without firebase-core?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since we don't need firebase analytics, I was wondering if the notifications has any link with firebase-core or none at all?
Unfortunately I can't test them before releasing the app.

Comment: Do you use it on Android or iOS?

Comment: On Android you can see how all the dependencies work with `./gradlew androidDependencies`.